# I'd like to position 'Read more' right after first part of text, where the dots would be in this example?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add 'read more' to appear straight after the first `<p>` text.

In this instance, it would be where the dots are positioned.

The code works and truncates the product description text, but 'read more' appears below the content in the wrong position.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
// Shorten product long description with read more button
function filter_the_content( $content ) {
// Only for single product pages
if( ! is_product() ) return $content;

// Set the limit of words
$limit = 14;

// Strip p tags if needed
$content = str_replace( array( '<p>', '</p>' ), '', $content );

// If the content is longer than the predetermined limit
if ( str_word_count( $content, 0 ) > $limit ) {
    // Returns an associative array, where the key is the numeric position of the word inside the string and the value is the actual word itself
    $arr = str_word_count( $content, 2 );
    
    // Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
    $pos = array_keys( $arr );
    
    // First part
    $text = '<p>' . substr( $content, 0, $pos[$limit] ) . '<span id="dots">...</span>';
    
    // More part
    $text .= '<span id="more">' . substr( $content, $pos[$limit] ) . '</span></p>';
    
    // Read button
    $text .= '<button id="read-button"></button>';
    
    $content = force_balance_tags( $text ); // needded
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {
        // Settings
        var read_more_btn_txt = 'Read more';
        var read_less_btn_txt = 'Read less';
        
        // Selectors
        var more = '#more';
        var read_button = '#read-button';
        var dots = '#dots';
        
        // On load
        $( more ).hide();
        $( read_button ).html( read_more_btn_txt );

        // On click
        $( read_button ).on( 'click', function() {
            if ( $( more ).is( ':hidden' ) ) {
                $( more ).show();
                $( dots ).hide();
                $( read_button ).html( read_less_btn_txt );
            } else {
                $( more ).hide();
                $( dots ).show();
                $( read_button ).html( read_more_btn_txt );
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<?php
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: pls create a re-producable running example so that we can check and let you know how tofix. Your crrent code have lot of php variables and due to this we can't run the above code straight-forward.

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh Sorry I'm not sure how I do this? I'm a beginner, if you have a wordpress test environment , it should work in the functions.php on any product page , any help appreciated :)

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh How do I push the 'read more' to the end after the hidden text has shown? Any ideas?

Comment: Just put your code into jsfiddle and I can't see any issue: https://jsfiddle.net/2q03brcw/1/